# Mysql set boolean to 1 when requirements are met all others with requirements to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an image table in a mysql database with the following fields

```
id         int primary key 
type_id    int
product_id int
source     varchar
created    timestamp
expiry     timestamp
active     tinyint
```

What I need to do is set 1 picture active ( `active=1` ) where the `product_id`, `source` and `type_id` is the same, the one that should be set active should be the one with the newest created timestamp and if I have 2 with the same timestamp I need the one with the highest id set active AND expiry should be > `CURRENT_DATE`, all others with the same product_id, source and type_id should have active set to 0. This should be done for all where product_id, source and type_id are the same.

Can this be done in 1 SQL?

Comment: Please edit your question to add sample data and expected results.

Comment: Yes it should be possible to do in one query (maybe with sub-queries, and/or aggregate functions). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to return the rows where `active` must be updated to `1` and `LEFT` join to the table in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update tablename t left join (
  select t.* 
  from (
    select *,
      row_number() over (partition by product_id, source, type_id order by created desc, id desc) rn
    from tablename
    where (product_id = source) and (product_id = type_id) and (expiry > currrent_date)
  ) t
  where t.rn = 1
) tt on tt.id = t.id
set t.active = (tt.id is not null)
```